# How do I spawn potions with Command Blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to get super speed, like a speed III for 1:00? I want it to be a splash potion that spawns from a command block, I know it can be done, since potions are entities.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, can't command blocks also just directly give effects, without bothering to spawn a potion?

Comment: @SaintWacko Yes if you use the command `/effect`

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the command `/summon`.

> Summons an entity (mobs, projectiles, items, vehicles, etc.).

The entity for the Potion is called "*ThrownPotion*". If you want a special effect to that Potion you have to use a variable where you are able to configure the effect.

The whole command looks like this

```
/summon ThrownPotion ~ ~ ~ {Potion:{id:373,Damage:8226,Count:1}}
```

The `~` indicates the relative coordination to the commandblock (you can change it to the coordinations where you want to spawn the Potion otherwise the Potion is spawing in the commandblock).

The variable `Damage` is the effect it will have and count is the `count` of how many Potions will be spawned.

A list of the effects you find on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potions#Data_value_table).

Comment: You can't use the word "then" yet you get self-righteous over people not using google. Have a -1.

Comment: @Studoku well I am sry for that removed it...

Comment: @Studoku I see it was mean but could you remove the -1 because it looks like my fully correct answer is wrong...

Comment: Hmm... oh, go on then.

Answer (score 1):

A more simple approach (and a more reliable approach) would be to use the `/effect` command directly. This directly gives the player a status effect as specified. The syntax is as follows:

```
/effect <player> <effect> [seconds] [amplifier] [hideParticles]
```

Where `<effect>` is the [status effect id](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Status_effects) (e.g. `1`, or `minecraft:speed`). So, for example, if you wanted Speed 3 for 60 seconds, the command is as follows:

```
/effect @p minecraft:speed 60 2
```

Note that amplifier is zero-indexed, that is to say that 0 corresponds to effect level 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:373,Damage:16385,Count:1,tag:{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:1,Amplifier:1,Duration:1000000,}],display:{Name:"Name of Item",Lore:["Line 1 of Lore","Line 2 of Lore"]}}}}
```

That command should summon a dropped potion.

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting the potion in your inventory rather than in effect, you will need to use droppers. Unfortunately they haven't made a way for a command block to do the job. Droppers should work well for a while. But this also means you must refill them often.

(I am using potions for a PvP map. If there is a different reason you want a potion-giving command, I probably don't have an answer, other then using your creative inventory or the answers above.)

Comment: Did you read the question? He asked how to do it with command blocks, not droppers.

Answer (score -1):

`/give @p minecraft:potion 1 18197`
 The `1897` is the code for splash potion of healing add a `1` in front for splash.

Comment: The question wants the entity, not the item

Answer (score -1):

```
/give @p slash_potion (amount) (id 1-40)
```